# Struggling with pivot_wider function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

I have a dataframe that contains consumption values of multiple liquids in an experiment, it looks something like this, but with tens of thousands of rows:

```
   ID Consumption  Liquid
1  F1  2.99282778  Control
2  F1  0.12895535  Experimental
3  F2  1.67459665  Control
4  F2  0.02716522  Experimental
```

I would like a tidy dataframe that instead looks like this:

```
   ID  Consumption_Control  Consumption_Experimental
1  F1  2.99282778           0.12895535 
3  F2  1.67459665           0.02716522
```

I have been trying to use the `pivot_wider` function in R

```
df_wide <- df %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = Liquid, values_from = Consumption)
  )
```

but get the following error:

```
Warning message:
Values from `Consumption` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
• Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
• Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates.
• Use the following dplyr code to identify duplicates.
  {data} %>%
  dplyr::group_by(ID, Liquid) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(n = dplyr::n(), .groups = "drop") %>%
  dplyr::filter(n > 1L)
```

I have tried suppressing the warning to no avail. What am I missing?

Comment: Does it help if you use `group_by(ID, Liquid)` before the pivot?

Comment: Do you have more than 1 experimental and 1 control for each ID?  If so that is causing the warning message.

Comment: Two things: (1) you have an extra paren in the third code block. (2) When I run that code, I don't get the error. I get the _structure_ of what you want, though the column names need to be refined. To get the exact output you requested, you can use `pivot_wider(df, names_from = Liquid, values_from = Consumption, names_glue = "{Liquid}_{.value}")`. In case it matters, R-4.3.2 and tidyr_1.3.0

Comment: But I can reproduce your error if instead of `df` I use `bind_rows(df, df[1,])` (a blatant duplication of one row). I think you need to work through the _logic_ of what should happen when one `ID` value has other than exactly one of each `Liquid` (including: missing one or 1+ of something).